# Configure Application Pool in a web publish package on IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, iis, msdeploy

I´m trying to configure the application pool to `.NET v4.5 Classic` from the default `DefaultAppPool` for a web service deployed in IIS 10, developed with Visual Studio 2019.

These are my steps:

- I created a file called `parameters.xml` in the root with the following content:

  ```
  <parameters>
      <parameter name="appPool" defaultValue="SealSignAppPool">
          <parameterEntry kind="DeploymentObjectAttribute" scope="application" match="applicationPool/@applicationPool" />
      </parameter>
  </parameters>
  ```
- Create the package from right click on the project -> publish:
  [image]
- The package is created and I can view the parameter correctly configured inside parameters.xml in the deploy zip:
  [image]
- After deploy, the Application Pool remains the default.

  [image]

**NOTE:** If I use Import Application Wizard with the zip deploy, I can see the parameter, but in the import log says it can´t be applied to any site...

[image]
[image]

**======================================================================**

**== UPDATE 1 ==**
I´ve added in `Web Deploy Package.pubxml` the missing properties:

```
<IncludeIisSettings>true</IncludeIisSettings>
<IncludeAppPool>true</IncludeAppPool>
```

With only `IncludeAppPool` nothing changes.
With `IncludeIisSettings` added I have a exception and the package publish fails with `"EscapeTextForRegularExpressions" task was not given a value for the required parameter "Text"`

I searched and the recomendations are set `IncludeIisSettings` to false... :(

Any idea what I missing??
Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to specify IncludeIisSettings=true to have the settings included in the zip.If you need the actual AppPool definition included, you should also set IncludeAppPool=true.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but don´t work. Update 1 added to the question... :(

Comment: For information about "Web Deploy Parameterization", you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-parameterization